# How do I initialize a new instance of a class when I call the AREL association the first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object

I inherited a project - controller has a custom action within which we set a couple instance variables:

```
@contact = @property.contact ? @property.contact : Contact.new
@contractor = @property.contractor ? @property.contractor : Contractor.new
```

I think the Rails way would be to initialize Contact.new and Contractor.new when I call @property.contact or @property.contractor if they don't exist instead of setting these up as instance variables in the controller.

But I don't know the syntax to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your app, it's far more likely that this logic belongs in the controller, where it is. Usually these things are done to pre-populate the association objects required for Rails to render a form correctly, so it's not something that really makes sense in the model itself, ie. for a `property.contact` method to return a `Contact.new` if one doesn't already exist doesn't (usually) make any logical sense, whereas setting the `@contact` variable in the controller/view to a new one for display purposes makes sense.

FWIW, the above code is precisely the same as the more concise:

```
@contact = @property.contact || Contact.new
@contractor = @property.contractor || Contractor.new
```